# In bash script, how to have a script that runs in the background and starts when an application is opened

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, bash

I'm making a script which should run when I open Safari. I want it to open when the user logs in and run in the background, then have part of the script to run when Safari opens.
Is this possible in bash script?

Comment: I haven't tried anything - as I can't find anything helpful on the internet @patrix

Comment: Do you have any script at all and are just missing the "check for Safari" part? Or is this your first bash script ever?

Comment: @patrix it's not my first bash script ever